# Using background image class multiple times

Tags: html, css

I've got a button background calss. I need to use it multiple times. How do I keep all common once separated and only have the url changed multiple times?

This is my css:

```
.menuBtnColour{
    position: relative; //common
    top: 0;//common
    left: 0;//common
    right: 0;//common
    bottom: 0;//common
    background-repeat: no-repeat;//common
    background-size: 50%;//common
    background-image: url(1.png); //can I keep this separated to be used together with the above?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have three buttons with the `.menuBtnColour` class. You want each to have three different backgrounds, and you don't want to achieve this using inline CSS.

You could give each another, more specific class. For example:

```
<button class="menuBtnColour btn1"></button>
<button class="menuBtnColour btn2"></button>
<button class="menuBtnColour btn3"></button>
```

Then, style the `.btn1`, `.btn2` and `.btn3` classes.

CSS:

```
.menuBtnColour{
    position: relative; //common
    top: 0;//common
    left: 0;//common
    right: 0;//common
    bottom: 0;//common
    background-repeat: no-repeat;//common
    background-size: 50%;//common
}

.btn1{
    background-image: url(1.png);
}
.btn2{
    background-image: url(2.png);
}
.btn3{
    background-image: url(3.png);
}
```